# How to show records from related models?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have 2 models, 1 for clients and 1 for jobs.  I wanted to display all the jobs for a particular client in the show.blade.php.  How do I fetch data the related data and display it in the show method?  Is there an easier way to do it in backpack or do I need to create a new method for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for nested resources. Here's a tutorial on how you can do it in Backpack: https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud